# How can I fill these holes?

Tags: repair

[image: Holes in internal wall]

Previous owner of our house left some large-ish holes in the wall. The biggest one is 8cm in diameter and the smaller ones are from dry wall anchor (Molly) bolts that I removed. They are about an inch wide. What's the best way to go about filling these?

Comment: put in a circular piece of drywall, tape it and patch it ... if it looks good, then you are done ... if it does not look good, then it is just practice ... cut the hole square as suggested in the answer below

Comment: Or don't fix it and put a tv up there to hide the damage.

Answer (score 3):

If this is drywall I would buy a small bucket of plaster and some drywall tape (the mesh kind), drywall knives and patch the smaller once that way. The bigger one I would cut a bigger square hole from stud to stud and cut a nicely fitting drywall piece to fit into the square. Fix it to the studs with drywall screws. Then use the same drywall compound and drywall tape to patch up the seems of the patch. All the stuff should be easy to get in the store. It takes some skills to get all of that smooth. Check out some drywall videos on youtube

Comment: Thank you, so you wouldn't recommend cutting a piece of circular drywall to fit in the gap and using a piece of wood to bridge it?

Comment: @JM The large hole appears to have some sort of ring inside it. You need to cut that out as you won't be able to get a smooth patch over it. Once you are doing that, rectangles are a **lot** easier to match up than circles.

Answer (score 2):

The small holes are easily filled with drywall compound and a putty knife.

The large hole can be repaired as Ride Sun suggested (by going to the studs so you have something to screw into) or you can get a strip of wood about the size of a paint stirring stick and slide it behind the drywall so it crosses the hole, then screw through the drywall into the wood.  Then you can put a round piece of drywall in the hole and screw it to the wood.  You'll have to add drywall compound to fill the round gap, of course.